# Is the 8pt grid a meaningful tool?

Tags: design, grid, space

In figuring out how well-known companies apply spacing in designing interfaces, I looked at a couple of mobile websites. Virtually none of them seem to apply a consistent grid system.

- Google, Booking and Behance largely follow a 4pt grid with fair
  consistency.
- Apple appears to be a hot mess of seemingly random
  spacing without system?
- Everyone else comes across to be doing their
  own thing, including Join, whose spacing isn't even steady between
  their different pages.

What am I missing? Why is it so popular when no one seems to follow it?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is.**

One thing up front: [Google recommends 8dp](https://material.io/design/layout/understanding-layout.html#principles) (not 8pt, but convertible for the same purpose). I'm not sure where you get the idea that these companies use a 4pt grid, but 4pt is still within the 8pt grid (we could argue that the 8pt grid is a 4pt grid, which is correct).

The thing about the 8pt (or 4) grid is that it fits most devices. And that includes Apple. Apple doesn't give a *fixed* number, but if you look at the examples, they all use the 8pt grid.

I understand that some companies have inconsistent spacing. Many of them don't even have a design system (though none of the ones you mentioned). But the 8 grid, while a relatively new fad, has been around for decades, and believe me, many designers use it. I'm a little confused by your last question, because in my experience it's just the opposite. Even the site you're asking this question on uses an 8pt grid!

## To summarize:

- It's used and tested by many quality design companies
- It's very easy to use, even by inexperienced designers
- Provides a consistent layout for designs
- It's very easy to adapt to almost any design system
- Looks great on any device and every DP resolution